# Ponteiro retornando valor de memoria

Tags: c

Galera boa noite, recorro a vocês para me nortear sobre o meu problema.

Seguinte, Estou desenvolvendo um trabalho para faculdade onde armazeno e exibo os resultados de ordenação de diversos algoritmos, sendo numero de comparações, trocas e tempo.
Tenho tudo pronto e escrito, ou seja, o escopo do trabalho esta Ok, falta implementar o resto dos algoritmos.

Consegui quase tudo com a ajuda de colegas de outro fórum, porém estou com um erro que não consigo soluciona-lo, se alguém puder me dar uma ideia do que esta acontecendo fico grato.

1- Aqui eu tenho minha lista global de registros que ira armazenar os resultados de ordenação:

typedef struct{
    int numcomp;
    int numtrocas = 0;
}ESTATISTICAS;

2-  Como exemplo o algoritmo bubble sort recebendo os valores por referencia:

void bubbleSort(int vet[], int num, ESTATISTICAS* estatisticas){

```
int i, continua, aux, fim = num;
        do{
            continua = 0;

            for(i = 0; i < fim -1; i++ ){

                estatisticas->numcomp++;    
                if(vet > vet[i+1]){
                    aux = vet;
                    vet = vet[i+1];
                    vet[i+1] = aux;
                    estatisticas->numtrocas++;
                    continua = 1;
                }
            }
            fim--;
        }while(continua != 0);
```

}

3- e aqui a declaração da lista e a chamada da função de ordenação com a exibição dos valores armazenados:

int *ptr;
                    ptr = geraVetor(vetor1);
                    //imprimeVetor(ptr, vetor1);

```
                ESTATISTICAS* estatisticas = (ESTATISTICAS*) malloc(sizeof(ESTATISTICAS)); 

                clock_t  start, end;

                start = clock();
                bubbleSort(ptr,vetor1, estatisticas);
                end = clock();
                printf("\n\nTROCAS: %d", estatisticas->numcomp);
                printf("\n\nTROCAS: %d", estatisticas->numtrocas);
```

4- O erro consiste em: quando compilo meu programa tudo esta ok, porém o valor retornado pela variável numcomp esta muito além do numero de comparações, se parecendo mais com um endereço de memoria. algo do tipo: 348219. Já a variável numtrocas o valor é retornado normalmente apos os incrementos ++;

Aguardo ajuda, de já agradeço.

Comment: Que compilador você está usando? Tentei compilar seu código usando gcc e dá erro no tydedef struct, ao fazer 'int numtrocar = 0'. Esse erro de compilação faz sentido, pois você não deveria inicializar o valor de uma variável em um typedef struct, você está apenas definindo um novo tipo. Ao criar uma variável desse novo tipo é que você deve inicializar os valores dela.

Answer (score 0):

Eu acho que seu problema vem do fato de que você não inicializou a variável numcomp da struct, você devia inicializá-la como 0, como fez com a numtrocas.

Além disso, eu percebi 2 coisas estranhas em seu código, que vou explicar a seguir:

### Falha ao compilar

Ao tentar compilar seu código com gcc, obtive o seguinte erro de compilação:

```
189566.c:1:44: error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘=’ token
typedef struct{ int numcomp; int numtrocas = 0; }ESTATISTICAS;
```

Isso significa que ele não estava aceitando a inicialização dessa variável numtrocas, quando tirei o ' = 0', funcionou.

Na minha opinião, isso faz sentido, pois você não deveria inicializar a variável dentro do typedef struct, pois no typedef você está apenas definindo um novo tipo, e ao criar variáveis desse novo tipo é que você deveria inicializá-las.

### Comparações no BubbleSort

Seu algoritmo BublleSort parece errado, os seguintes warnings que recebi ao compilar explicitam o problema:

```
189566.c:17:11: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
    if(vet > vet[i+1]){
           ^
189566.c:18:9: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     aux = vet;
         ^
189566.c:19:9: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     vet = vet[i+1];
         ^
```

O que está acontecendo aqui é que você está comparando um ponteiro (vet) com um inteiro (vet[i+1]). O certo seria vet[i] > vet[i+1].

---

Após as alterações que julguei necessárias, o seguinte código funcionou pra mim:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    int numcomp;
    int numtrocas;
}ESTATISTICAS;

void bubbleSort(int vet[], int num, ESTATISTICAS* estatisticas){
    int i, continua, aux, fim = num;
    do{
        continua = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < fim -1; i++ ){

            estatisticas->numcomp++; 
            if(vet[i] > vet[i+1]){
                aux = vet[i];
                vet[i] = vet[i+1];
                vet[i+1] = aux;
                estatisticas->numtrocas++;
                continua = 1;
            }
        }
        fim--;
    }while(continua != 0);

}

int main() {
    //int *ptr; ptr = geraVetor(vetor1); //imprimeVetor(ptr, vetor1);

    int ptr[5] = {4,2,6,3,7};

    ESTATISTICAS* estatisticas = malloc(sizeof(ESTATISTICAS));
    estatisticas->numcomp = 0;
    estatisticas->numtrocas = 0;

    bubbleSort(ptr,5, estatisticas);
    printf("\n\nCOMPARACOES: %d", estatisticas->numcomp);
    printf("\n\nTROCAS: %d", estatisticas->numtrocas);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

bom dia ! Consegui resolver o problema apenas inicializando as variáveis. Não sei o motivo do typdef não aceitar a inicialização, tudo bem, consegui. Muito obrigado por ter ajudado, fique com Deus abraços.